# Copy windows file size from folders only

Tags: windows, excel, file, size

I would like to write the file size of each file in a particular folder to Excel. How can I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You want to do this in Excel? Copy it from *where*? To where? What do you mean by "in bulk"?

Comment: Please read your question before posting it. It is completely unclear, what you want to achieve.

Comment: apologies.i have a bunch of files in a windows folder and i just want to extract their file size. and paste it in a list in excel

Comment: @andreas, I have edited the question to reflect the problem you are facing.

Comment: I do not believe this can be done without code, so I do not think it should be moved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileSystemObject object to work with files, folders and textstreams:

```
''Reference: Windows Script Host Object Model

Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim fldr As Folder
Dim f As File
Dim i As Integer

Set fldr = fs.GetFolder("C:\docs\")

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    i = 1
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        .Cells(i, 1) = f.Name
        .Cells(i, 2) = f.Size
        i = i + 1
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned anything about programming, I think this belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), but you just need to select all the files, right-click, select Properties, and copy the Size.